# Why is Python Geolite always returning LA when I have used UK IP address?

Tags: python

I tested it with Japan and UK sites, just to see if it was accurate to the right country at least and all I get is the same result from the guide below....LA America

Im using GeoIP and GeoLite.

So I go online and follow this quick usage guide:
http://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/
Then I hop into my terminal and run the lines of code...and the example shown returns an LA based location, as the guide shows...all good so far.

So I exit my terminal and open an editor to see if I can write this into a saved .py file that I can run with one command if needed (at least started to anyway)

I testedIt seems that no matter what  I do it returns LA America...All I did was write the lines of code into an editor and add print statements to return the info to me...heres the code:

```
from geoip import geolite2

# IP for google.co.uk 
match = geolite2.lookup("216.58.198.163")
match is not None
print(match.country)
print(match.continent)
print(match.timezone)
print(match.subdivisions)
```

The code runs alright and returns info at least, but no matter what country IP Address for testing I am only getting LA America (like the guide showed)

Heres what I get everytime:

```
US
NA
America/Los_Angeles
frozenset(['CA'])
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to make it show the correct location please?

NOTE: my method for obtaining the IP's is by opening my BASH terminal and simply entering:

```
$ host www.google.co.uk
google.co.uk has address 216.58.198.163
```

and:

```
$ host www.google.co.jp
www.google.jp has address 209.85.202.94
```

Comment: What makes you think 216.58.198.163 is an 'UK IP address' ?

Comment: Interestingly, for me both `host www.google.co.uk` and `host www.google.co.jp` return the same value: `172.217.6.99`. I infer there are many different computers that provide `www.google.co.uk`, with one chosen that is nearby to the requestor.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, the guide I used failed to mention that GeoLite2 and GeoIP require the use of an up to date database file (.mmdb) to provide a Geo-location for an IP address within a Python program.

The database was free to download and I also found an example showing it's use. I now have the program written nicely. The user is prompted to enter a valid IP and relatively accurate information is returned.

I can now even take the returned Longitude and Latitude values and use a website to narrow down the search area a little bit.

Thanks for the replies. And I now understand that an IP address can have different locations to the URL (for example a www.something.co.uk address may not return a UK location, especially so with a site like Google who have servers/computers worldwide)